# Rails Var Dump at bottom of page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am working with rails 3 i have the following model

my controller

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController  
   def index    
    @surveys = Survey.active  
   end
end
```

and my view

```
<%= @surveys.each do |p| %>  
    <li><%=p.id %>-<%=p.name %></li>
<%end%>
```

my anticipated outcome is that it for each through the surveys variable outputting the id and name in a li. which it does however it also dumps the variable out at the bottom of the page.

```
1-name
[#<Survey id: 1, name: "name", is_active: true, user_id: nil, open_script: "Opening Script", voicemail_script: "Voice Mail Script", closing_script: "Closing Script", email_script: "Email Script", created_at: "2012-12-19 15:17:36", updated_at: "2012-12-20 03:46:35">]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable dump comes from this line

```
<%= @surveys.each do |p| %>
```

This `<%=` means evalue ruby code and output it, when this `<%` just evalute. Change you code to something like this:

```
<% @surveys.each do |p| %>  
    <li><%=p.id %>-<%=p.name %></li>
<%end%>
```